# Getting the trimmed mean with Python

Tags: python, math

I need to find the trimmed mean within a list of number using Python.

I need the mean of the number list minus the max and min number from that list. 
Eg. list= 10, 20, 30 40. I need to get the mean from 20 and 30.

So far I have :

```
print "The ordered list is:", sorted(list)
u = list[1:-1]
u = list[1:-1]
print "These numbers trimmed are:",u
print "The trimmed mean is:",sum(u)/l(u)
```

l = lenght of list, this however, leaves me with an error:

print "The trimmed mean is:",sum(u)/l(u)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

But this

Comment: should just be `l`, not `l(u)`

Answer (score 1):

```
def trimmed_mean(lst):
    trimmed_lst = sorted(lst)[1:-1]
    return sum(trimmed_lst) / len(trimmed_lst)
```

then

```
>>> trimmed_mean([10, 20, 30, 40])
25.0
```

Answer (score 0):

replace this:

```
sum(u)/l(u)
```

to:

```
sum(u)/len(u)
```

some changes: using `list` as variable name is bad practice, as list is inbuilt in python

```
my_list = sorted(my_list)
print "The ordered list is:", my_list
u = my_list[1:-1]      # you need this only once
print "These numbers trimmed are:",u
print "The trimmed mean is:",sum(u)/len(u)
```